# chef knife ec2 server create: error when spinning up new ec2 servers

Tags: amazon-ec2, chef, knife

I'm trying to use knife ec2 server create to automatically launch ec2 instances for the first time, but I'm getting `"ERROR: Excon::Errors::BadRequest: Expected(200) <=> Actual(400 Bad Request)"`.

When using `knife ec2 server list` the list of existing servers is returned, which means the AWS IDs in `.chef/knife.rb` are correct.

I  checked AMI ID using [Ubuntu's AMI Finder](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/), and tried different combinations of all other parameters, so can't figure out what's wrong.

I'm using is:

```
knife ec2 server create \
    -r "role[memcached]" -I ami-d0f89fb9 -f m1.small \
    -i mysshkey.pem --ssh-user newuser \
    --region us-east-1b -Z us-east-1b
```

(there is a Chef role called `memcached`, there's a file in the local directory called `mysshkey.pem`)

Environment: Win7, Git 1.8.1.msysgit.1, Chef/Knife 11.4.4. I will try later doing the same from a Linux workstation, so I can isolate if the problem is the environment, or paramenters, or AWS credentials.

Any idea how to troubleshoot knife ec2 scripts?

Comment: Just as a random aside, you will also see that same error if you hit your EC2 instance cap like I just did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the problem.

The parameter `-i <AWS_SSH_ID>` is not used to specify the SSH key itself, but the security *name* of the SSH Pair Key used when you created your credentials within AWS.

After adjusting this, `knife ec2 create` started to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

`us-east-1b` is not a valid EC2 region. Try `us-east-1`.

Comment: Same thing. Also tried using Knife under ubuntu 13.04, and exact same error.